# Charge distribution on Spherical conducting shells

Tags: electrostatics, charge, gauss-law, conductors, coulombs-law

For example we have very thin conducting spherical shells of radius R and 2R. Initially the smaller shell has Q and other shell has q charge of their own, now there will be charge induction in them then we say that smaller has same charge but the bigger gets new charges on its botth surfaces due to induction. 
 My question is that we consider inductions by smaller on bigger, but won't we also have charge induction by bigger on small and thus have new charges coming on surfaces of smaller spherical shells?[image]

Comment: Assuming the smaller shell were not present, what is the electric field like inside the larger shell?  Given that field, what sort of induction  would you expect?

Comment: There will be no field inside bigger shell so there will be no induction, yes I understood. Thanks